# ios 6.1.1 device won't run xcode 4.6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.6, ios6.1

I just updated my iphone 4S to ios 6.1.1 from 6.1 over the weekend b/c it said it was a critical update. However, now when I try to test my app on the phone using Xcode 4.6, it says "Xcode cannot run using the selected device."  I checked the apple site for updated but didn't see any xcode updates. Any ideas?

EDIT: I opened the Xcode preferences and checked for updates and it said there weren't any but then my phone suddenly started working again though.  Thanks for the comments and input.

Comment: Isn't iOS 6.1.1 still under NDA?

Comment: I think you need to re-enable your device for development. (Xcode organizer, find your device and check the light is green) Also as @trojanfoe has said... 6.1 is the latest public release which can be discussed.

Comment: OK, now suddenly it's working again. I just went into the Preferences to check for updates and it said there weren't any. Hmmm...

Comment: In weird scenarios like this, quit xcode or reset simulator settings... these surely help to solve the problem...

Comment: iOS 6.1.1 is the latest public release for iPhone 4S (see http://istheapplestoredown.com/ios ) and not under NDA. I can test apps with Xcode 4.6 on my iPhone 4S.

Comment: I didn't know you could run Xcode on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed itself after checking for updates in xcode preferences.